# Expressing the idea of "gory details"

Tags: phrase-choice

On seeing an usage of

> I've been ignoring the ***gory details*** of xxx ...

I've been using the phrase since to express the idea in similar situations, without knowing the actual meaning of it, or the word ***gory***.

Glad that I checked it up *before* putting it down in my formal writing, only when did I realized that it means ***bloody** details*.

So, to express such idea of *"unnecessary"* details, but still in a *respectful* way, like *"the ___ details of <strike>the</strike> quantum mechanics"*, what's the more appropriate phrase(s) for formal writing?

Comment: If you want to convey "incredibly complex", you could refer to the ***arcane / esoteric / enigmatic** details of quantum mechanics*. But you wouldn't normally use such exotic terminology for details of more "comprehensible" matters, which are simply an unnecessary level of detail for the context. By which I mean that quantum theory is a "special case", that *no-one* really understands, no matter how deeply they look into the details.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Didn't Dick Feynman say 'just do the math'?

Comment: Collectively, they all say *Just shut up and calculate!* ...so they call themselves [the “shut-up and calculate” school.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22shut+up+and+calculate+school%22)

Comment: ...what *Feynman* said was *Anyone who claims they **understand** Quantum Theory... **doesn't**!*

Comment: "The *minute* details of..." also conveys the idea that these are small and not worth exploring right now.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - didn't Feynman say something like 'the technical term for what happens if you try to understand quantum mechanics is "going down the toilet"'?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I had a spell of reading some of those (I now think) awful popular books about physics, e.g. The Dancing Wu-Li Masters, The Tao of Physics. Someone called their authors 'Von Dänikens of the intellect'.

Comment: @stangdon: Indeed - or just *We can ignore the **minutiae** of XXX*, where one definition of ***minutiae*** is *the small, precise, **or trivial** details of something*.

Comment: You could just leave out "gory". ***For the purposes of this paper we can ignore the details of quantum mechanics***. Whilst **gory** on its own does mean bloody, the colloquialism **gory details** is taken to mean fine or intricate or detailed without any blood involved. I guess it originally came from taking a general view of, say, an animal without dissecting it.

Comment: @PeterJennings - Surely the implication is that the topic the details are about is distasteful or shocking? I assume it comes from describing a surgical operation or a wound in great detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 'gory details' is an idiom that isn't to be taken literally. If you want to say it in a way that is more fitting for formal writing, I suggest

> I've been ignoring the **finer** details of quantum mechanics . . .

There are two meanings of [fine](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fine) at play here –

> very exact and delicate, or needing to be done, treated, or considered very carefully:
> *I understood in general what she was talking about, but some of the finer details/points were beyond me.*

and

> of excellent quality or much better than average:
> *We had lunch in one of the city’s finest restaurants.*

So although you are ignoring the detail, you are complimentary about it.

Comment: Thanks. I normally wait till the community voted before I pick my answer. Meanwhile, would you agree with the comment that 
Peter Jennings made, that _"gory details is taken to mean fine or intricate or detailed **without any blood involved**"_, If so, would you add some comments to the  _"gory details"_ usage(s) to the top of your answer please?

Comment: @xpt I have added something.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Weather Vane provided a great answer with "finer". If you want to keep the not-entirely-seriously pejorative tone of "gory", you could use "messy", as the phrase "messy details" is quite common. Here is an example:

> The Fredericksburg woman divorcing her husband laid out all the messy details, including the most secret of them all. (Ian Shapira, "[CIA divorces: The secrecy when spies split](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/style/cia-divorces-the-secrecy-when-spies-split/2012/03/05/gIQAPpBZAS_story.html)," *Washington Post*, 14 March 2012)

Comment: Thanks. +1, but I'll wait for the community voted result to pick my answer.